# PostgreSQL: Why can't subqueries as expressions return more than one row, but functions can?

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, subquery

If I try to create a column whose value is a select returning more than one row, I get an error.

```
=> select (select 1 union select 2);
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

But if I create a function that does the same thing, I get the behavior I want.

```
=> create or replace function onetwo() returns setof integer as $$
$> select 1 union select 2 
$> $$ language 'sql' strict immutable;
CREATE FUNCTION
=> select onetwo();
 onetwo 
--------
      1
      2
```

Why the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While OMG Ponies answer is entirely correct I'd rather put it like this: You're confusing `SELECT f()` with `SELECT literal`.

- `SELECT f()` *executes* a function and returns its result. And, a table returning function can also be written as `SELECT * FROM f()` -- which is even more elegant. Because Pg doesn't yet have stored procedures -- less scheduling they can be done through functions -- we use `SELECT` as Microsoft SQL uses `EXECUTE`
- `SELECT LITERAL` is a method of returning a literal (something that can fit in a row/column).

Comment: +1, and I think I have seen the `SELECT f()` (for set returning function `f`) form described as a syntactic sugar for `SELECT * FROM f()`.  It's only implemented because it's unambiguous and a convenient shorthand.

Answer (score 5):

It's not an apples to apples comparison.

```
select * 
  FROM (select 1 
        union ALL 
        select 2)
```

...is equivalent to your function.

A column in the SELECT clause can only return a single value per record.  Which is impossible with your UNION example.  So I converted it into a derived table/inline view, which is what is happening with the function example.